# Unable to login using smtp

Tags: python, outlook, smtp, gmail

I input the correct email / password but it still unable to login to that mail / unable to send message with that mail so therefore it is outputing **The username or password you entered is incorrect** Can anyone help me identify the problem and come up with a good solution please.

Thank you

-me

```
def Emailspam():
print("Choose your email provider")
print("1. Gmail")
print("2. Outlook")
provider = input(CRED + ">>> " + CEND)
os.system("cls")

useremail = input("EMAIL : ")
userpass = input("PASSWORD : ")
os.system("cls")

victimemail = input("Victim email : ")
Content = input('Message : ')
Number = int(input("Number of mail to send : "))
os.system("cls")

#https://www.androidauthority.com/gmail-smtp-settings-801100/#:~:text=SMTP%20server%20address%3A%20smtp.gmail,SMTP%20port%20(SSL)%3A%20465
if provider == ("1"):
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    port = 587
#https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040
elif provider == ("2"):
    smtp_server = 'smtp.office365.com'
    port = 587

else:
    print("Invalid choice")
    skrr = input("press enter to close")
    exit()

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.login(useremail,userpass)

    for i in range(0,Number):
        print("Number of Message Sent to " + victimemail + ":" , i+1)
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.sendmail(useremail,victimemail,Content)
        time.sleep(1)

    server.close()

except Exception as e:
    print('The username or password you entered is incorrect.')
    p = input("Press enter to close")
    exit()
```

Comment: You are getting the message The username or password you entered is incorrect because that's what your code says to do. The *real* cause of the error is in `e`. Try printing that in your error message instead.

Comment: It said SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server

Comment: So now you know that there is a problem with the server refusing your connection that has nothing to do with wrong credentials.

Comment: got it thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an app password and then see if it works. For creating an app password, go to your account and go into the privacy settings to set it up. Also, try to add:

```py
server.ehlo()
```

after:

```py
server.starttls()
```

Comment: I have edit the code and it still giving same problem please check. I have also turned off my less security app access from my gmail account.

Comment: Did you try to make an "App password"?

Answer (score 0):

Google has increased their security. So you won't be able to login to any gmail account if you haven't turned off your less security app access from your gmail account. To do that first click manage google account > Security tab > Less secure app access > Off . This is a article for it:[How to turn off less secure app access in gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Another thing is that you shouldn't keep the login code in your for loop. You should login outside the for loop. So you will login once and send email with that account many time.

Hope that it helps!

Here is the working code:

```py
def Emailspam():
    print("Choose your email provider")
    print("1. Gmail")
    print("2. Outlook")
    provider = input(CRED + ">>> " + CEND)
    os.system("cls")

    useremail = input("EMAIL : ")
    userpass = input("PASSWORD : ")
    os.system("cls")

    victimemail = input("Victim email : ")
    Content = input('Message : ')
    Number = int(input("Number of mail to send : "))
    os.system("cls")


    if provider == ("1"):
        smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        port = 587

    elif provider == ("2"):
        smtp_server = 'smtp.office365.com'
        port = 587

    else:
        print("Invalid choice")
        skrr = input("press enter to close")
        exit()

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(useremail,userpass)

        for i in range(0,Number):
            print("Number of Message Sent to " + victimemail + ":" , i+1)
            server.sendmail(useremail,victimemail,Content)
            time.sleep(1)

        server.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print('The username or password you entered is incorrect.')
        p = input("Press enter to close")
        exit()
```

Comment: Oh yes i kept that in the loop thank you for bringing that up to me.

Comment: I have edit the code and it still giving same problem please check. I have also turned off my less security app access from my gmail account.

Comment: I have uploaded the code. You need to starttls befor logging in. Now the code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

using server.connect and moving few things outside of the loop will fix it

```
 def Emailspam():
        print("Choose your email provider")
        print("1. Gmail")
        print("2. Outlook")
        provider = input(CRED + ">>> " + CEND)
        os.system("cls")
    
        useremail = input("EMAIL : ")
        userpass = input("PASSWORD : ")
        os.system("cls")
    
        victimemail = input("Victim email : ")
        Content = input('Message : ')
        Number = int(input("Number of mail to send : "))
        os.system("cls")
        
        #https://www.androidauthority.com/gmail-smtp-settings-801100/#:~:text=SMTP%20server%20address%3A%20smtp.gmail,SMTP%20port%20(SSL)%3A%20465
        if provider == ("1"):
            smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
            port = 587
        #https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040
        elif provider == ("2"):
            smtp_server = 'smtp.office365.com'
            port = 587
        
        else:
            print("Invalid choice")
            skrr = input("press enter to close")
            exit()
    
        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
            server.connect(smtp_server,port)
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.login(useremail,userpass)
    
    
            for i in range(0,Number):
                print("Number of Message Sent to " + victimemail + ":" , i+1)
                server.sendmail(useremail,victimemail,Content)
                time.sleep(1)
    
            print("Finished")
            server.close()
    
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('The username or password you entered is incorrect.')
            p = input("Press enter to close")
            exit()
```